# Laravel Auth::user()->name and Auth::user()->id is not working

Tags: php, laravel

Hi im storing data in database but when i use `Auth::user()->name` it is not working. in my other controller its working. But when i hard coded the name and the id it works.  I already imported auth and still get the same issue. Thanks for the help. this is weird .

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\ForumPost;
    use Auth;


    public function create_discussion(Request $request){ 

        $create = new ForumPost ; 
        $create->post_content = $request->content;
        $create->user_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $create->comment_frequency = 100;
        $create->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $create->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Discussion created successfully '
        ]);
    }
```

btw im using vue as a front-end.

Comment: How are you authenticating your app with vue? Please can you show your routes file(s).

Comment: Im not using any authentication in my api routes.

Comment: I just want to get the currentlyblogged in user name and id

Comment: If you're not using authentication for the routes then how is there meant to be an authenticated user? Are you saying that there is a logged in user for your web routes and it's not showing for your api routes?

Comment: `if (Auth::check()) {/* user is authenticated and accessible  */}` or better `if (!Auth::check()) { abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.'); }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import/add

```
use Auth;
use App\User;
```

Than save logged in user as this in your controller:

```
public function create_discussion(Request $request, $id){ 

    $create = new ForumPost ; 
    $create->post_content = $request->content;
    $create->user_name = auth()->user()->name;
    $create->comment_frequency = 100;
    $create->->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $create->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Discussion created successfully '
    ]);
}
```

This is from Laravel 7.14. You are not passing the id in your function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i already imported the user model and auth and did what you typed above but still error 500 internal server error.

Comment: Please check you model. Add protect fill in it. That is one of the reason for 500 error. If doesn't work put your controller, model and blade file in question.

Comment: i use $guarded = []

Answer (score 1):

You can Use in your controller

get User to your controller.. user auth in your controller head.

```
use Auth;
use App\User;
```

**Get User id from :**

```
Auth::id();
```

**Get User Name from**

```
Auth::user()->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you are logged in.
and use that

```
auth()->user()->name;
auth()->id();
```

it's the same.
if error 500 , check the .env is exists then try

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: thanks i managed to get it working by adding props instead of using the auth. i also try that command but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not authenticed user, then `Auth::user()->id` won't work.
Do a `Auth::check()` before, to be sure that you are well logged in :

```
public function create_discussion(Request $request){ 

    if(Auth::check()){
          $create = new ForumPost ; 
          $create->post_content = $request->content;
          $create->user_name = Auth::user()->name;
          $create->comment_frequency = 100;
          $create->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
          $create->save();

          return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Discussion created successfully '
          ]);
     } else {
         return response()->json([
                'message' => 'You are not authentic user. '
         ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sir i added the auth check but it hits the else statement which is user is not authenticated. But the user is already logged in. my another question if user is logged in does that mean the user is authenticated ? ?

Comment: Yes, logged in user are authenticated user

Comment: Thanks. User is already logged in but its hitting the else statement idk why.

Comment: Api routes is has default auth middleware right? so in the first place if im not logged in it will not redirect me to the controller method. but it hits the controller method so that means i am logged in but when i user the auth()->id... it is not working its response is error 500

Answer (score 0):

Before creating a forum you can do an auth()->check()

```
if(auth()->check()){ //returns true or false
    $user = auth()->user();
    $create = new ForumPost ; 
    $create->post_content = $request->content;
    $create->user_name = $user->name;
    $create->comment_frequency = 100;
    $create->user_id = $user->id;
    $create->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Discussion created successfully '
    ]);
}else{
     return response()->json(['message'=>'not authenticated could not create a forum.']);
}
```

may be this will work.

Comment: Still not working. User is already logged in so that means i can use auth()->func but still not working idk why this happen.

Comment: are you using an api route ?? if soyou need to specify the api guard.
try   auth('api')->user()  maybe it will work

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get it working by creating a props and pass it to my post request. I dont know why that auth()->user()->.... is not working.I think this will be a problem when the proj. is getting larger. Thanks for the answers